# Cannot Read Context in Dialogflow Fulfillment (Suddenly Undefined)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

We built a Dialogflow agent using google cloud functions as webhook which worked properly until yesterday evening. At that time I exported the agent and reimported it later on and it worked for a while.

What stopped working is that `agent.context.get('...');` (also `agent.getContext('...')`) does return `undefined` even if the context is set according to the UI and raw API response.

As an example I have an intent which has a required slot `shop`, webhook for slot filling enabled. 
When I test the agent, the intent named `info` is matched correctly and also the context `info_dialog_params_store` seems to be there:

[image: Intent]

And here is part of the output context according to the raw API response:

```
"outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects/MYAGENTNAME/agent/sessions/0b753e8e-b377-587b-3db6-3c8dc898879b/contexts/info_dialog_params_store",
        "lifespanCount": 1,
        "parameters": {
          "store": "",
          "store.original": "",
          "kpi": "counts",
          "date_or_period": "",
          "kpi.original": "trafico",
          "date_or_period.original": ""
        }
      }
```

In the webhook I mapped the intent correctly to a js function:

```
let intentMap = new Map();
intentMap.set('info', info);
agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
```

And the first line of the `info` function looks like:

```
function info(agent) {
    store_context = agent.context.get('info_dialog_params_store');
}
```

Which returns

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at info (/user_code/index.js:207:36)
    at WebhookClient.handleRequest (/user_code/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:303:44)
    at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:382:9)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:762:7
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:745:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

I am quite sure that I did not change anything which could affect the proper functioning of agent, except some refactoring.

I also tried the beta functions activated as well as deactivated as I read that there can be issues with environments, but that did not change anything.

Anyone knows in which direction I can investigate further?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, I resolved it updating dialogflow-fulfillment in package.json:

from  "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0"
to **"dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.0"**

Comment: Thanks for the tip. At that time, this version was not available but maybe they fixed something to prevent this error from occurring.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by turning off "Beta features"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvUwo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I could fix it by the following 'magic' steps:

- Copied my original function to a text file
- Copy and pasted the original example code into the GUI fulfillment code editor ([Code on GitHub](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js))
- Deployed the function
- Created a minimal example for my `info` function:

```
function info(agent) {
    store_context = agent.context.get('info_dialog_params_store');
}
```

- Tested it, and it worked
- Copied back my original code
- Everything was fine again