# Getting parameters in the follow up intent from previous intent

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I follow up an intent for intent let's say "master intent" to have a child intent follow as  yes and no response intent

If it's yes i want to get the parameters from the master intent 
I am trying to access it using  context like this :

```
var name = agent.context.get('saveContact.saveContact-yes').params['name'];Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

but I don't know what to put in the get 
Is it the context name ? or  intent name for the master or the specific child intent  name  ? 
I tried the both and get Null

I've got Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
in the log .

Libraries :

```
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.13.1",
    "googleapis": "^27.0.0",
    "actions-on-google": "2.2.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.4.1"
```

rest of the code :

```
function SaveContact(agent){
 //var name = agent.parameters.name;
 var name = agent.context.get('saveContact.saveContact-yes').params['name'];
 var email = agent.context.get('saveContact.saveContact-yes').params['email'];
// var email=agent.parameters.email;
   return admin.database().ref('/contacts').push({name: name,email:email}).then((snapshot) => {
 // Redirect with 303 SEE OTHER to the URL of the pushed object in the Firebase console.
     agent.add('added sucessfully');
// console.log('database write sucessful: ' + snapshot.val());
});
}
```

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response }); /// Thid is to handle the communication with dialogflow
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('makeAppointment', makeAppointment);  // It maps the intent 'Make Appointment' to the function 'makeAppointment()'
  intentMap.set('saveContact-yes', SaveContact);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);

});
```

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55550129/edit) your question to include the rest of your code, including the libraries that you're using? This looks valid on the surface, but there may be other parts of your code that could be causing the problem.

Comment: The rest of the codes is just the basic stuff , 
I include the Libraries

Comment: Really, the rest of the code would help, at least for that handler function.

Comment: Okay, I edit it

Comment: Have a look here: Looks similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55039936/dialogflow-context-suddenly-undefined

Comment: Also try doing this '#saveContact.saveContact-yes'
https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents/actions-parameters#from_contexts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the latest version of the dialogflow-fulfillment library. It looks like, from your `package.json` you are using version 0.4.1, which had a different way of working with contexts.

`agent.context.get()` was introduced in version 0.6.0, with the previous method being deprecated.

You can update to the latest version using `npm install --save dialogflow-fulfillment@latest`